# How can I check a value entered in a field on my form is a number?

Tags: php

How can I check a value entered in a field on my form is a number?

ex:

```
$values = array(1,20,10);
```

Comment: In your example `$values` is not a number it is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use function :
is_numeric() — Finds whether a variable is a number or a numeric string ..

for example :

```
<?php
$tests = array(
    "42", 
    1337, 
    "1e4", 
    "not numeric", 
    array(), 
    9.1
);

foreach ($tests as $element) {
    if (is_numeric($element)) {
        echo "'{$element}' is numeric", PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "'{$element}' is NOT numeric", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
'42' is numeric
'1337' is numeric
'1e4' is numeric
'not numeric' is NOT numeric
'Array' is NOT numeric
'9.1' is numeric
```

source : http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Answer (score 2):

This might help:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Answer (score 1):

You could check the input from the form using [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to know is if it is a number, then PHP has a function called [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) that returns true if it's numeric.

However, if you want to know if something is an integer, don't use `is_int`.  Use `filter_var($variable, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)`.

If you want to know if something is a float (such as 1.00123): `filter_var($variable, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)`.